# MakeIndex indexing \texttt{} under "Symbols" and not by letter

Tags: indexing, typewriter, makeindex

I've began adding an index to my Latex project using `imakeidx` and have run into a small problem:

When writing the code

```
\index{\texttt{float} data type}
```

my index shows up as the following:

[image: wrong index]

It is showing the keyword in a new "Symbols" section which is not what I want. I assume this happens because `\makeindex` sees the `\` and assumes it is not a regular word.

I've tested this by simply reverting back to

```
\index{float data type}
```

and it indexes just fine

[image: correct index without monospace]

but now my word is no longer monospaced which I desire.

Here is the relevant code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

...

\makeindex[columns=2, intoc]

\begin{document}
    ....

    The \texttt{float} data type\index{\texttt{float} data type} is the smallest
    real type, if they differ at all.

    ...

    \printindex
\end{document}
```

and the following `.mst` file:

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\Large\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}}\\vspace{1mm}\\nopagebreak\n"
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
delim_1 "\\dotfill"
delim_2 "\\dotfill"
```

How can I have a monospaced font in my index while simultaneously putting it under the correct letter?

Comment: `\index{float data type@\texttt{float} data type}`

Comment: @egreg Thank you! Is much easier than I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How egreg said, use the argument `@` in index entry:

```
\index{<sort>@<word>}
```

`<sort>` is how to sort the term and `<word>` is how the term should appear in the index.

If you will index more data types, maybe will be interesting you treat it with subentries. To do this, you use the argument `!`:

```
\index{<main entry>!<subentry>}
```

In your case, I think this will be good:

```
\index{data type!float@\texttt{float}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise it would be so easy.